# Jquery Validation Submit Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation library - everything is working great. All my rules/methods etc. However, I just noticed that when I submit, I am getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

**JavaScript**

```
...
'submitHandler': function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
...
```

The form is submitting - I'm using a standard post (not ajax) and according to the docs, I'm calling the submit correctly. Not sure why that error would be coming up?

Comment: (As a rule of thumb, if an error say something like "object is not a function" then use `console.log` to figure out what it **is**).

Comment: The object is the form - so that's looking good. Looking at the response that you posted - I do have a fieldset with an id of "submit" so that could be causing the error. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The object in question (the one which is not a function) is the value of the `submit` property of the form (you can tell because that is the object you are trying to use *as* a function and so is the only thing that an error like that could be complaining about).